# How to detect doubletap on a View?

Tags: android, uiview, gesture-recognition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - basic gesture detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection)

I'm trying to have a View sensitive to double taps on an Android.  So far, I learned to set up the double tap and know what place to handle the event for action:
API: android.view.GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener

```
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    …
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
    …
    mGestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(new MyDoubleTapListener());
    …
    private class MyDoubleTapListener implements GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {                         
                                    return false;                      
    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    return false;
                    }
}
```

But How do I link it to the View?  This is in a class that has a few View members.

I'll really appreciate you helping me connect the dots!

Answer (score 6):

Your view needs to implement the **onTouchEvent()** method, and that method needs to pass the event along to the **onTouchEvent()** method of the **GestureDetector** object.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    Log.v(DEBUG_TAG,"OnTouchEvent !!!");
    boolean result = gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(event);//return the double tap events
    return result;
}
```