# Developing comic book

Tags: android, effects

I am hoping to develop an android application which would contain comic books for viewing. Google Play has a Marvel Comics application that I would like to emulate since I like that type effect in my application. However, I'm having trouble starting

The effect is when the user double taps on comic part, only that part of image scales to fit the screen. The other areas on the image can be seen using a swiping effect, but it remains zoomed in. Once the user is finished with viewing the zoomed in image, another double tap will return the user to the original screen.

Are there any good links for me to look at? What is this feature called?

Answer (score 1):

I would look at this - [Is there a built in API for handling pinch-zoom functionality in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645648/is-there-a-built-in-api-for-handling-pinch-zoom-functionality-in-android) - which covers the zoom API,
And this - [How to detect doubletap on a View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640119/how-to-detect-doubletap-on-a-view) - which covers double tapping on a view

Answer (score 1):

Finally I used HTML5 for doing this type of animation. and its works perfectly in all device.