# How to listen to doubletap on a view in android?

Tags: android

I want to detect a `doubletap` on a view, like for example a `button`, and then know which view it was. I have seen [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640119/how-to-detect-doubletap-on-a-view) but the question they say it is a duplicate of it does not seem to answer my question.

All I can [find](http://www.41post.com/4194/programming/android-detecting-double-tap-events) is to add a `GestureDetector` to the activity, and add a `OnDoubleTapListener` to it. But that is only triggered if I tap on the background/layout of my screen. It is *not* triggered when I (double)tap a `button`.

This is the code I have inside my `onCreate`:

```
    gd = new GestureDetector(this, this);


    gd.setOnDoubleTapListener(new OnDoubleTapListener()  
    {  
        @Override  
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)  
        {  
            Log.d("OnDoubleTapListener", "onDoubleTap");
            return false;  
        }  

        @Override  
        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e)  
        {  
            Log.d("OnDoubleTapListener", "onDoubleTapEvent");
            //if the second tap hadn't been released and it's being moved  
            if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)  
            {  

            }  
            else if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)//user released the screen  
            {  

            }  
            return false;  
        }  

        @Override  
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e)  
        {  
            Log.d("OnDoubleTapListener", "onSingleTapConfirmed");
            return false;  
        }  
    });
```

Comment: Perfect code on this method handle on single tap or double tap :)

Answer (score 26):

You can achieve this by just using these few lines of code. It's that simple.

```
final GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){


       //here is the method for double tap


        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {

            //your action here for double tap e.g.
            //Log.d("OnDoubleTapListener", "onDoubleTap");
           
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            super.onLongPress(e);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }


    });

//here yourView is the View on which you want to set the double tap action

yourView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            return gd.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

Put this piece of code on the activity or adapter where you want to set the double tap action on your view.