# How to set my motion listener for exist view

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

for instance, add double tap listener for VideoView. I hope it support following code:

```
//Player.kt
var vv = findViewById(R.id.player) as VideoView
vv.onDoubleClick {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Did you checked this code to work in IDE? Did it work? Can't see a problem here. Please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: @voddan, it's ok code, I just wanna know how to customize view listener

Comment: Sorry, I still do not follow you. Could you please modify the question?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What have you tried (code)?  What was wrong about the result that you want help with?  Did you receive a specific error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I hope it support following code:
>   ...

Most likely the syntax that you've shown here is inspired by [Anko](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) library which has some extension functions allowing you to add the `View` listeners in this pretty fashion:

```
button.onClick {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Hi there!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

instead of wordy Java syntax:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hi there!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, Anko doesn't have the `onDoubleClick` extension function (well, the `View` doesn't have the `setOnDoubleClickListener()` method, either). If you want to add double-click support to your views, you need to use [GestureDetectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530937/how-to-listen-to-doubletap-on-a-view-in-android). And, if you wish to write this code with the help of extensions functions, like in Anko, documentation can be found [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html).