# How detect double tap left and right in android on any type of view

Tags: android, exoplayer, gesturedetector

last two days i search this query but i cannot find any solution. I ant to detect the double tap left and right on exoplayer video. I used gesturedetector to check double tap but i cannot find a way to detect left and right double tap.

Comment: just detect double tap in general as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530937/how-to-listen-to-doubletap-on-a-view-in-android and using screen coordinates assess whether it was a double-tap on the right edge of the screen or on the left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You could get coords of tap from MotionEvent object, calculate center of target view (via x,y, height, width) and then handle this data;

2) You could use two transparent overlays and set listeners to them )