# Double tap using GestureDetector

Tags: android, touch-event

How do I modify this code below so that when a user double taps on the screen the apps/puzzle restarts? any help is much appreciated.

```
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent( MotionEvent event ) {
        detector.onTouchEvent( event );
        return true;
    }

    private class DoubleTapHandler
            extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent( MotionEvent event ) {
            int touchY = ( int ) event.getRawY( );
            // y coordinate of the touch within puzzleView is
            // touchY - actionBarHeight - statusBarHeight
            int index = puzzleView.indexOfTextView( touchY
                    - actionBarHeight - statusBarHeight );
            if( puzzleView.getTextViewText( index )
                    .equals( puzzle.wordToChange( ) ) )
                puzzleView.setTextViewText( index, puzzle.replacementWord( ) );
            return  true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution but works :)

```
private fun setDoubleClick() {
    var numOfClicks = 0
    [View].setOnClickListener {
        numOfClicks++
        if (numOfClicks == 2) {
            //onDoubleClick
            numOfClicks = 0
        } else {
            Handler().postDelayed({ numOfClicks = 0 }, 2000/*Set this according to desired doubleclick speed*/ )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I’ll try it and see But I’m using java language ... I’m also new to android programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {


    //doubletap method


    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {

        //put what do you want when double tap
         restartApplication();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        super.onLongPress(e);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }


});
```

Now attach the detector your view touch listener

```
yourView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()

{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event){

    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
});
```

Here is the restart function

```
void restartApplication(){
    Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/39816509/12676247

Comment: Okay but i need to be able to doubleTap and app restarts automatically. is this formula similar to that as well?

Comment: edited the answer for restart Application when double-tap

Comment: Thank you so much for help, it has worked like a charm here. again thank you so much sir...I don't know how to thank you