# Android How to detect double tap?

Tags: javascript, android, double-click, gesturedetector

I'm trying to refresh `Canvas` on `DoubleTap` in android. I use `GestureDetector` in custom `View`.

```
final GestureDetector mDetector = new GestureDetector(
    getContext(), new GestureDetector.OnGestureListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the error

> The method onDoubleTap(MotionEvent) of type new
>   GestureDetector.OnGestureListener(){} must  override or implement a
>   supertype method

with

```
Remove '@Override' annotation
```

solution. I remove override and get this warning

> The method onDoubleTap(MotionEvent) from the type new
>   GestureDetector.OnGestureListener() {} is never used locally.

Then I tried to test whether this works and made a function to change `TextView` string whenever I `DoubleTap`. Nothing happens.

I also looked at [GestureDetector Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html) for explanations, but they don't even have `DoubleTap` there, which everybody uses. What should I do?

Comment: I think the following link will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640119/how-to-detect-doubletap-on-a-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
final GestureDetector mDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {

        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Nope it does not work. `The value of the local variable Detector is not used` - highlighted mDetector warning.

Comment: I check whether stuff works by writing this function - `text = MainActivity.text` `text.setText("stuff")`

Comment: With some other sources I made it work, but now I have a problem - I use this in `WebView`, so double tap zooms in and out, and I have `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener`. When I use also `SimpleOnGestureListener` zooming is disabled.

Comment: please note that the warning "The value of the local variable Detector is not used" is not an error, so you need to set the detector `mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);`. Try to read this is vr useful https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

Comment: Yep. This link did the thing, but again, now zooming feature's disabled. How can I keep both of them?

Comment: i suggest to close this question and open another one where you'll able to post more detailed code for this issue (in this way more people can help you)

Answer (score 2):

For the ones, who were wondering how to set it also to the corresponding view:

```
final GestureDetector gDetector = new GestureDetector(getBaseContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        doIt();
        return true;
    }
});

// Set it to the view
mButton.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> gDetector.onTouchEvent(event));
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach to this problem was different since I needed to perform something for the onClick listener as well, and also it was in a list view, so I needed to know what was the item content.
here is my approach using kotlin Job:
At the top of the class I've declared something like this:

```
private var doubleTapTimerJob: Job = Job()
private var clickedViewItem: CartViewItem? = null
val DOUBLE_TAP_DELAY = 200L
```

where CartViewItem is the model that is used in the list.
and this is my onClickListener logic:

```
if (clickedViewItem == null || clickedViewItem != cartViewItem) {
    doubleTapTimerJob.cancel()
    doubleTapTimerJob = lifecycleScope.launch {
        delay(DOUBLE_TAP_DELAY)
        clickedViewItem = null
    }
    clickedViewItem = cartViewItem
    onClicked(cartViewItem)
} else {
    onDoubleClicked(cartViewItem)
    clickedViewItem = null
    doubleTapTimerJob.cancel()
}
```

here I wait for 200 milliseconds for the second tap, and if it didn't happen, I will make clickedViewItem null, so its not valid anymore

Comment: It seems possible now to override the functions
`onSingleTapConfirmed(e: MotionEvent)` and `onDoubleTap(e: MotionEvent)` to get the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate, Android doesn't deliver the `ACTION_MOVE` and `ACTION_UP` events to your listener if you didn't handle the corresponding `ACTION_DOWN` event first, i.e. returned `true` in the listener.

#### Option 1

```
val listener = object: SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return true // <<< This bit is important.
    }

    override fun onDoubleTap(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        // This now works.
        // ...
    }

    override fun onDoubleTapEvent(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        // This now works.
        // ...
    }

    override fun onSingleTapConfirmed(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        // This now works.
        // ...
    }
}
```

#### Option 2

```kotlin
view.setOnTouchListener { _, event -> 
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event) || event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
}
```

Comment: Returning `true` from `onDown` was the real trick. Wasted a whole night trying to figure out why the other events were not firing. Finally found the solution. What a relief! Thanks.