# Like A Post With Heart Animation (DYNAMICALLY SET)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to (on double tap of a container), show a heart animation on screen. I want it to be with the like_button library (which already has the heart animation I want), BUT instead of the user clicking the like button, I want it to be the use double tapping on a container. I know this isn't supported with that library, but has anyone made a fork of it or changed it so that it is possible? Thanks! Here is some example code you can use to test out the library:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:like_button/like_button.dart';

class LikeAnimationWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LikeAnimationWidgetState createState() => _LikeAnimationWidgetState();
}

class _LikeAnimationWidgetState extends State<LikeAnimationWidget> {
  bool liked = false;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 100),
        LikeButton(
          onTap: (bool isLiked) async {
            setState(() {
              liked = !isLiked;
            });
            return !isLiked;
          },
          isLiked: liked,
          size: 200,
          circleColor:
              CircleColor(start: Color(0xff00ddff), end: Color(0xff0099cc)),
          bubblesColor: BubblesColor(
            dotPrimaryColor: Color(0xff33b5e5),
            dotSecondaryColor: Color(0xff0099cc),
          ),
          likeBuilder: (bool isLiked) {
            return Icon(
              Icons.favorite,
              color: isLiked ? Colors.deepPurpleAccent : Colors.grey,
              size: 50,
            );
          },
          countBuilder: (int? count, bool isLiked, String text) {
            var color = isLiked ? Colors.deepPurpleAccent : Colors.grey;
            Widget result;
            if (count == 0) {
              result = Text(
                "love",
                style: TextStyle(color: color),
              );
            } else {
              result = Text(
                text,
                style: TextStyle(color: color),
              );
            }
            return result;
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override the function `onTap` in the `LikeButton` class and implement a `GestureListener`. Likely there will even be one already implemnted for you to just modify. This could be done by creating a class `MyLikeButton` and extending the `LikeButton` class. You can then use the `@Override` Tag to override the `onTap` function and make it, so that the `onTap` event is triggered when you doubleTap.

How to implement the doubleTap gesture with gesture listener can be read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038219/android-how-to-detect-double-tap)